# List sorting in groovy

Tags: sorting, groovy

I have a book book list and it contains book id, publisher name, contact number, address, book release date and book status (active, deleted, suspended) . I want to sort a list based on the following criteria:

1. Sort it by activation date
2. Sort the publisher name from A to Z
3. If there are two publisher name in the same date range then it should sort it as per book status and the order should be active > suspended > deleted (This is not alphabet sorting)

For example, the result should be:

```
Activation Date: 18.10.2014
Test Book, ABC publisher, active
Test Book2, ABC publisher, suspended
Book3, XXYYBB publisher, active 

Activation Date: 19.10.2014
Test Book5, XXYYBB publisher, deleted
Test Book3, ZZZZ publisher, active
Test Book4, ZZZZ publisher, suspended
```

My sample code:

```
booklist.sort{ x,y ->
  x.activateDate <=> y.activateDate ?: x.publisherName <=> y.publisherName
}
```

how to do the third manual check for the book status?

Comment: is the `book.status` a string or some enum, ...

Comment: Since sorting is generally performed in *ascending* order, I think you mean 'active < suspended < deleted`, not the other way around.

Comment: @BalRog I think he want's us to read it as "active is more important than suspended"

Comment: @cfrick, I suppose, but that's rather the opposite of what the actual expression psuedocode means.

Comment: @Abhilash Ghosh, in your first grouping of desired results, you have a publisher name of `'A...'` sorting in front of a publisher name of `'X...'` (alphabetic order). However, in your second grouping, you have a publisher `'Z...'` sorting in front of `'X...'` (reverse alphabetic order). Which is correct? Or did you intend for all to have the same publisher so as to demonstrate the desired (tertiary) status sorting?

Comment: @Cfrick, the book.stautus is a field not a enum.

Comment: @BalRog, sorting is done as per the date and publisher name. If there are more the one publisher name in the that date, then it should check for order status. The order status should be in order active then suspended then deleted (Please note that order status is not sorted in any order rather its just a rule that if there are more publisher then it should be sorted as mentioned above.)

Comment: Hmmm. I don't understand. There is more than one publisher name on the first date (`ABC Publisher` and `XXYYBB Publisher`), and yet you one of the two books with `active` status sorted AFTER the book with `suspended` status, as if you are sorting by publisher name before status. There is also more than one publisher name on the second date (`ZZZZ Publisher` and `XXYYBB Publisher`) and yet here you are sorting strictly by status, ignoring the publisher names. I'm glad you liked my solution, but please note that my solution will not produce your sample results.

Comment: @BallRog, the rule is simple first it should look up the activation date, then it should sort the publisher name alphabetical order. If the publisher name appears twice in the same date then it should manually sort the list as per the order mentioned above.

>> There is also more than one publisher name on the second date (ZZZZ Publisher and XXYYBB Publisher)... <<

If you look at the sample result then on 18.10 ABC publisher appears twice however their status is different. So I am sorting with active first then suspended and so on..Same thing is also happening on 19.10

Comment: @Abhilash Ghosh, no, on 19.10 there is a difference. You are sorting `XXYYBB Publisher` last when it should  be first, unless you have some truly counterintuitive sorting rules.

Comment: @BalRog, you are correct. it was a typo. i have edited that so that later on someone can lookup for the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1: `enum`

If the status is indeed limited to the three exact values given, you should probably already be using something like this anyway:

```
enum BookStatus { active, suspended, deleted }
```

Then in the Book class:

```
class Book {
    ...
    BookStatus status
}
```

Since Enum classes already have a natural sort order (order of declaration) you are all set, just add another elvis (`?:`) clause to your comparator closure:

```
booklist.sort { x, y ->
    x.activateDate <=> y.activateDate ?:
        x.publisherName <=> y.publisherName ?:
        x.status <=> y.status
}
```

### Solution 2: Status-ordering `List`

See @cfrick 's solution

### Solution 3: Status-ordering `Map`

There are only a couple of minor advantages of this solution over the List-based solution:

- Average key search through a `LinkedHashMap` has algorithmic complexity *O(1)* while average element search through an `ArrayList` has *O(n)*.
- `statusOrder[x.status] <=> statusOrder[y.status]` is a marginally simpler expression than `statusList.indexOf(x.status) <=> statusList.indexOf(y.status)`

Here `Book.status` is assumed to be a `String`:

```
final statusOrder = [ active:0, suspended:1, deleted:2 ].asImmutable()
booklist.sort { x, y ->
    x.activateDate <=> y.activateDate ?:
            x.publisherName <=> y.publisherName ?:
            statusOrder[x.status] <=> statusOrder[y.status]
}
```

---

If I were for some reason unable to use the `Enum` solution, I would probably use the `List` solution unless there were a large (more than 20?) number of status values, in which case I would use the `Map` solution.

Answer (score 2):

in case these are strings, you can use a list to define the importance and then use the index in this list with the ufo-operator

```
final order = ['active','suspended','deleted']

def l = [
        [status: 'deleted'],
        [status: 'active'],
        [status: 'suspended'],
        [status: 'active'],
        [status: 'suspended'],
]

println l.sort{ a,b -> order.indexOf(a.status) <=> order.indexOf(b.status) }
// -> [[status:active], [status:active], [status:suspended], [status:suspended], [status:deleted]]
```

Comment: As stated in @BalRog 's answer, the best thing would be to use enums (basically ints) to do this.  this answer aims for "easynes" and small lists, where performance is no concern.

Comment: Well, an enum in Java or Groovy is a first-class object with it's own behavior and internal state. You can even make enums with modifiable internal state (but I don't recommend that). One of the implicit behaviors of each enum constant is to return its own ordinal position, but that doesn't make it "basically an int". It's more like a Pascal concept of an "abstract data type" than the C/C++ concept of enum-as-list-of-int-constants.